# swrlx:makeOWLThing is creating only one individual

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

Using Protege and SWRL tab, I have the ontology mentioned hereinafter. It is composed of the Class `Test` and the class `Shadow`, where `Test` has three individuals `t1, t2, t3`. I was trying to define an SWRL rule that creates an individual of `Shadow` class for each existing individual of `Test`, the rule is

```
Test(?x) ^ swrlx:makeOWLThing(?new, ?x) -> Shadow(?new)
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Only one individual of `Shadow`, named `fred` is created, instead of three (corresponding to `t1, t2, t3`).
2. How to control the naming of the resulting individual which is always named `fred`?

   ```
   Prefix(:=<http://www.semanticweb.org/hilal/ontologies/2016/5/untitled-    ontology-58#>)
   Prefix(owl:=<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>)
   Prefix(rdf:=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>)
   Prefix(xml:=<http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>)
   Prefix(xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>)
   Prefix(rdfs:=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>)                
   Ontology(<http://www.semanticweb.org/hilal/ontologies/2016/5/untitled- ontology-58>

   Declaration(Class(:Shadow))
   Declaration(Class(:Test))
   Declaration(NamedIndividual(:t1))
   Declaration(NamedIndividual(:t2))
   Declaration(NamedIndividual(:t3))
   Declaration(AnnotationProperty(<http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#isRuleEnabled>))



   ############################
   #   Named Individuals
   ############################

   # Individual: :t1 (:t1)

   ClassAssertion(:Test :t1)

   # Individual: :t2 (:t2)

   ClassAssertion(:Test :t2)

   # Individual: :t3 (:t3)

   ClassAssertion(:Test :t3)


   DLSafeRule(Annotation(<http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#isRuleEnabled> "true"^^xsd:boolean) Annotation(rdfs:comment ""^^xsd:string) Annotation(rdfs:label "S1"^^xsd:string) Body(BuiltInAtom(<http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.3/swrlx.owl#makeOWLThing> Variable(<new>) Variable(<x>)) ClassAtom(:Test Variable(<x>)))Head(ClassAtom(:Shadow Variable(<new>))))
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

SWRL rules cannot create new individuals, as far as I understand the DL Safe conditions.

Comment: it already did, using built-in functionality. Please check swrlx:makeOWLThing in this link http://wiki.ruleml.org/index.php/SWRL

Comment: Which reasoner supports this?

Comment: Pellet! I am using Pellet with protege 5 and those rules could be written at SWRL tab.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you linked to [an article](http://wiki.ruleml.org/index.php/SWRL) describing the semantics of that extension:

> One of the the first built-ins I implemented provided the ability to create new individuals in a controlled manner. There is a detailed explanation in [2], but basically a built-in called swrlx:makeOWLThing creates a new individual and binds it to its first unbound argument; a new individual is created for each unique pattern of the remaining arguments.

Now, let's take a look at your rule as written in the question:

> Test(?x) ^ swrlx:makeOWLThing(?new, ?x) -> Shadow(?new)

If the atoms are processed from left to right, then ?x should be bound when makeOWLThing is encountered, but ?new isn't.  That means that you should get a new individuals bound to the variable ?new, and for each value of ?x you should get a different value of ?new.  That's what it sounds like you want.  However, in the code you posted, I see this:

```
DLSafeRule(
  Annotation(<http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#isRuleEnabled> "true"^^xsd:boolean)
  Annotation(rdfs:comment ""^^xsd:string)
  Annotation(rdfs:label "S1"^^xsd:string)

  Body(
    BuiltInAtom(<http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.3/swrlx.owl#makeOWLThing>
      Variable(<new>)
      Variable(<x>))
    ClassAtom(:Test Variable(<x>)))

  Head(
    ClassAtom(:Shadow Variable(<new>))))
)
```

I'm not certain, but if that's processed from left to right as well, the **makeOWLThing(?new,?x)** appears *first*, in which case ?x would be unbound when the new individual is created, so you'd only get one new individual.

Comment: I tried switching the order of the atoms, to make it: `Body(ClassAtom(:Test Variable(:x)) BuiltInAtom(<http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.3/swrlx.owl#makeOWLThing> Variable(:new) Variable(:x)))Head(ClassAtom(:Shadow Variable(:new))))` However, the SWRL two body axioms at the original SWRL rule were switched. And the same result, I still get one `fred` indidvidual!