# How to define a class Road to be equivalent to a set of objects with the same value of hasRoadNumber data property

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege, rdfs

I defined class `RoadSegment` and datatype property `hasRoadNumber`. So, now I want to define class `Road` and state that a `Road` is a set of `RoadSegments` with the same road number. How it can be done?

Comment: I. e. you want to generate new individuals like this: `:newRoad1 :hasSegment :segment1WithRoadNumberE95`? Try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817229/7879193.

Comment: Yes, I want to infer that these RoadSegments together create a Road. But I am afraid that that way of defining a Road is too computationally expensive. How do people usually deal with such situations? Do they create Road individuals explicitly?

Comment: Are you limited to OWL? If not, this is easier with SHACL.

Comment: No, I am not limited, the question is which databases support all these needed tools. My goal is to create a system for analysing traffic on roads, so I thought I can infer different facts from basic roads state, for example speed limits, traffic lights states, vehicle speed at specific point. So basically there will be a lot of points and a lot of vehicles.. Does it make sense?

Comment: Also, there is a need to define sequences, since vehicle motion is a sequence of points, and "be before" that point is crucial...

Comment: Check [this](https://phd.pietercolpaert.be/) out. Might be of interest for your work.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me that this work loosely related to semantic tech and inference in OWL knowledge representation languages..

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this data

```
<r123> a :Road; :number "123".
<r123.1> a :RoadSegment; :number "123"; :seq 1.
<r123.2> a :RoadSegment; :number "123"; :seq 2.
```

You can easily infer what you want with this GraphDB rule (.pie):

```
id: roadSegments
  r <rdf:type> <Road>
  rs <rdf:type> <RoadSegment>
  r <number> n
  rs <number> n
  -------------
  r <hasSegment> rs
```

The benefit is that the rule is dynamic, i.e. as you add/remove/edit segments, `:hasSegment` will be updated dynamically.

As for sequences, there are various patterns to represent them.

- `rdf:List` is standard but quite unwieldy.
- Using a sequence number makes things easier, eg https://schema.org/ItemList uses it (but unlike above, allows an item to be member of several lists, using auxiliary class https://schema.org/ListItem.