# How to state that a class is related to ALL instances of another class via a property

Tags: owl, protege

Have two questions

1. Given classes `A`, `B` and object property `p` (`A->B`). How to say that for any `a` from `A` and any `b` from `B` `a` is mapped via property `p` to `b` (`a p b`)?
   In other words `A` has property `p` and every instance of `A` is mapped to all instances of `B` via propery `p`.
2. Now we have 3 classes `A`, `B`, `C` and 2 properties `p1` (`A->B` or domain `A`, range `B`) and `p2` (`B->C` or domain `B`, range `C`).
   How to say in Protege that for any `a` from `A` and any `c` from `C` there exists a `b` from `B` for which `a p1 b` and `b p2 c`?

Comment: 1) should not be possible in OWL, i.e. you can't express a cartesian relation, but you can use SWRL: `A(x), B(y) -> p(x,y)`

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/16990106/7879193 or SWRL.

Comment: 2) Try `swrlx:makeOWLThing`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817229/7879193